# FusedLocations doesn't send location updates when map.isMyLocationEnabled = false. Strange behaviour

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I want to add a custom image as the my location indicator. 
The only way to hide the blue dot is to setIsMyLocationEnabled = false. Doing this somehow also disables the updates from FusedLocation. I want to know if this is intended or its just a bug?

Gradle -

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Activity (unnecessary code removed)-

```kotlin
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        startLocationUpdate()
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    private var marker: Marker? = null
    private var lastLocation: Location? = null

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        val icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location_indicator)
        val location = lastLocation?.let { LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude) } ?: sydney
        val markerOpts = MarkerOptions().position(location).flat(true).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .icon(icon)
        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOpts)
        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().zoom(17f).target(location).build()
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false // disabling MyLocation here stops FusedLocation updates
        mMap.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
    }


    fun startLocationUpdate() {
        val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                lastLocation = location
            }

        val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 1000
        locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 0f
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, object :
            LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                // Never gets called when mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false but works properly
                // if mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true. 
                marker?.position = LatLng(p0.lastLocation.latitude, p0.lastLocation.longitude)
                val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(latlng).zoom(17f).build()
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
            }
        }, Looper.getMainLooper())

    }
}
```

Layout-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.temp.MapsActivity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the location request. The LocationRequest by default has a low priority so it wont update very often.

When set `mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = false` it takes the default priority which is low. Just adding 2 lines solved the problem.

1. `locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`
2. `locationRequest.interval = 5000`